# Framework for Creating a Real Time and Two Player Web Application

Tags: web-applications, real-time

I need to create a Facebook Game that enables two users to play simultaneously. Can anyone give me some sort of frameworks, platforms or tools that will help me achieve this? I have knowledge in PHP, MySQL, JavaScript.

Comment: Something Like this? - http://parasyte.github.io/melonJS/examples/platformer/ ?

Comment: Can this create multiplayer games?

Comment: A: YES - indeed you are correct!

Answer (score 0):

Use all three with jquery framework and AJAX requests. I've done something similar with a browser based card game.

Comment: Can you give me a link to see a demo of your game? Please. I am worrying of problems that my server may encounter if thousands of players will play the game.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for Realtime.co.

You can use a real-time framework such as Realtime.co. In fact two games that are on Facebook (one of them on close beta) are using us as their multiplayer communication layer. You can find one of them here: https://apps.facebook.com/244946772280792/ and the other one's GodZ (https://www.facebook.com/godzgame).

Both use Flash/ActionScript but Realtime offers APIs for several languages (JavaScript, PHP, .Net, etc.).

For more information about the APIs, check here: http://www.xrtml.org/

Feel free to contact me for any help you may need as I am the Developer Evangelist for the company :)